# Paraview crash with Nvidia omniverse connector, possible vtk, qt5, libc error?

Tags: qt5, vtk, libc, paraview, omniverse

I'm trying to install the paraview connector to Nvidia omniverse. Once I load the plugin, it crashes with the following error. It looks like some issues with libc.so or Qt5. But I do not know what exactly is the problem and how I can deal with it.
The paraview install works fine without omniverse connector.

```
AutoMPI: SUCCESS: command is:
 "/usr/local/bin/mpiexec" "-n" "6" "/usr/local/bin/pvserver" "--server-port=36395"
AutoMPI: starting process server
-------------- server output --------------
Waiting for client...
AutoMPI: server successfully started.
free(): invalid pointer

Loguru caught a signal: SIGABRT
Stack trace:
72      0x561c3c15e1fe paraview(+0x91fe) [0x561c3c15e1fe]
71      0x7f4381b3d0b3 __libc_start_main + 243
70      0x561c3c15e007 paraview(+0x9007) [0x561c3c15e007]
69      0x7f43801d8116 QCoreApplication::exec() + 150
68      0x7f43801d03ab QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 299
67      0x7f4380229435 QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 101
66      0x7f4379fb44a3 g_main_context_iteration + 51
65      0x7f4379fb4400 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x52400) [0x7f4379fb4400]
64      0x7f4379fb417d g_main_context_dispatch + 637
63      0x7f436e91a32e /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5(+0x7932e) [0x7f436e91a32e]
62      0x7f438059635b QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 187
61      0x7f43805bc10b QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent*) + 603
60      0x7f43805ba7d3 QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::MouseEvent*) + 1763
59      0x7f43801d180a QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) + 394
58      0x7f438131e0f0 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 816
57      0x7f4381314a66 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 134
56      0x7f43813761ec /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5(+0x1cc1ec) [0x7f43813761ec]
55      0x7f4381373ce4 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5(+0x1c9ce4) [0x7f4381373ce4]
54      0x7f438131d457 QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent(QWidget*, QMouseEvent*, QWidget*, QWidget*, QWidget**, QPointer<QWidget>&, bool, bool) + 439
53      0x7f43801d180a QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) + 394
52      0x7f438131e343 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 1411
51      0x7f4381314a66 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 134
50      0x7f43814a1adb QMenu::event(QEvent*) + 347
49      0x7f43813572b6 QWidget::event(QEvent*) + 646
48      0x7f438149f4d2 QMenu::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) + 626
47      0x7f438149e4ae /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5(+0x2f44ae) [0x7f438149e4ae]
46      0x7f4381496d12 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5(+0x2ecd12) [0x7f4381496d12]
45      0x7f4381310aa2 QAction::activate(QAction::ActionEvent) + 242
44      0x7f438130e3e6 QAction::triggered(bool) + 70
43      0x7f43801fd1d0 QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) + 2000
42      0x7f43819a9f0d pqManagePluginsReaction::managePlugins() + 221
41      0x7f4381518c6d QDialog::exec() + 461
40      0x7f43801d03ab QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 299
39      0x7f4380229435 QEventDispatcherGlib::processEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 101
38      0x7f4379fb44a3 g_main_context_iteration + 51
37      0x7f4379fb4400 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x52400) [0x7f4379fb4400]
36      0x7f4379fb417d g_main_context_dispatch + 637
35      0x7f436e91a32e /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5(+0x7932e) [0x7f436e91a32e]
34      0x7f438059635b QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents(QFlags<QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag>) + 187
33      0x7f43805bc10b QGuiApplicationPrivate::processWindowSystemEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::WindowSystemEvent*) + 603
32      0x7f43805ba7d3 QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent(QWindowSystemInterfacePrivate::MouseEvent*) + 1763
31      0x7f43801d180a QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) + 394
30      0x7f438131e0f0 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 816
29      0x7f4381314a66 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 134
28      0x7f43813761ec /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5(+0x1cc1ec) [0x7f43813761ec]
27      0x7f438137335d /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5(+0x1c935d) [0x7f438137335d]
26      0x7f438131d457 QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent(QWidget*, QMouseEvent*, QWidget*, QWidget*, QWidget**, QPointer<QWidget>&, bool, bool) + 439
25      0x7f43801d180a QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2(QObject*, QEvent*) + 394
24      0x7f438131e343 QApplication::notify(QObject*, QEvent*) + 1411
23      0x7f4381314a66 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*) + 134
22      0x7f43813572b6 QWidget::event(QEvent*) + 646
21      0x7f438140b035 QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*) + 229
20      0x7f438140ae73 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5(+0x260e73) [0x7f438140ae73]
19      0x7f4381409a2e /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Widgets.so.5(+0x25fa2e) [0x7f4381409a2e]
18      0x7f4381409806 QAbstractButton::clicked(bool) + 70
17      0x7f43801fd1d0 QMetaObject::activate(QObject*, int, int, void**) + 2000
16      0x7f4380f8ff37 pqPluginDialog::loadPlugin(pqServer*, bool) + 2919
15      0x7f4380f8cc62 pqPluginDialog::loadPlugin(pqServer*, QString const&, bool) + 82
14      0x7f4380c63229 pqPluginManager::loadExtension(pqServer*, QString const&, QString*, bool) + 169
13      0x7f437fd4b5a6 vtkSMPluginManager::LoadLocalPlugin(char const*) + 150
12      0x7f437f09e083 vtkPVPluginLoader::LoadPluginInternal(char const*, bool) + 4227
11      0x7f437f09c474 vtkPVPluginLoader::LoadPluginInternal(vtkPVPlugin*) + 948
10      0x7f437f09b16c vtkPVPlugin::ImportPlugin(vtkPVPlugin*) + 1436
9       0x7f437f0a7b1f vtkPVPluginTracker::RegisterPlugin(vtkPVPlugin*) + 1551
8       0x7f437d2be644 /usr/local/lib/libvtkCommonCore-pv5.9.so.1(+0x440644) [0x7f437d2be644]
7       0x7f437fccc7a1 vtkObject::vtkClassMemberCallback<vtkSIProxyDefinitionManager>::operator()(vtkObject*, unsigned long, void*) + 113
6       0x7f437fcc5365 vtkSIProxyDefinitionManager::HandlePlugin(vtkPVPlugin*) + 469
5       0x7f4381bafcac /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x99cac) [0x7f4381bafcac]
4       0x7f4381bae47c /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x9847c) [0x7f4381bae47c]
3       0x7f4381ba63ee /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x903ee) [0x7f4381ba63ee]
2       0x7f4381b3b859 abort + 299
1       0x7f4381b5c18b gsignal + 203
0       0x7f4381b5c210 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x46210) [0x7f4381b5c210]
(  36.129s) [paraview        ]                       :0     FATL| Signal: SIGABRT
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: For starters, do not use autompi.

Comment: @MathieuWestphal, thank you. Tried with autoMPI turned off, the issue persisted.

Comment: where do you get the omniverse connector from ?

Comment: @MathieuWestphal, here is the link of the connector documentation. https://docs.omniverse.nvidia.com/con_connect/con_connect/paraview.html. It is directly downloased and installed by Nvidia's Omniverse launcher.